# Tracking NSLayoutConstraint Crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, stack, nslayoutconstraint

I have an issue with some `NSLayoutConstraint` setups which has appeared from iOS9 (I think). Anyway, I get the following console error:

> This NSLayoutConstraint is being configured with a constant that
>   exceeds internal limits.  A smaller value will be substituted, but
>   this problem should be fixed. Break on void
>   _NSLayoutConstraintNumberExceedsLimit() to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future.

Followed by:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint
>   constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]:
>   A constraint cannot be made between a leading/trailing attribute and a
>   right/left attribute. Use leading/trailing for both or neither.'

Then a bunch of stack info:

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102b3af65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001025aedeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102b3ae9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000102177e82 +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:] + 299
    4   My App                            0x000000010011f429 -[APStatisticsAverageFlightDuration viewDidInit] + 2841
    5   My App                            0x000000010011e909 -[APStatisticsAverageFlightDuration awakeFromNib] + 73
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010328752e -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2416
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010307284d -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000103073179 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001032aad85 -[UITableViewController loadView] + 84
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010307347c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 139
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000103073c7d -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001037ded8e __67-[UIStoryboardEmbedSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 524
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001035cf189 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 460
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001035cef8c -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001035cf250 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 156
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000103073687 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 662
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001030b6c26 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 54
    18  UIKit                               0x00000001030b74dd -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 433
    19  UIKit                               0x00000001030b7633 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 116
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001030b8879 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 890
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001030b967d -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010325163d -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 248
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000102f9911c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 710
    24  QuartzCore                          0x000000010146f36a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    25  QuartzCore                          0x0000000101463bd0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    26  QuartzCore                          0x0000000101463a4e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    27  QuartzCore                          0x00000001014581d5 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    28  QuartzCore                          0x00000001014859f0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 508
    29  UIKit                               0x0000000102f1253a _afterCACommitHandler + 174
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a669d7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a66947 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a5c59b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a5be98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    34  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000106016ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    35  UIKit                               0x0000000102ee8676 UIApplicationMain + 171
    36  My App                            0x000000010026c2cf main + 111
    37  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010491f92d start + 1
    38  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

How am I supposed to track down which constraint is causing the problem? I have dozens and dozens. I have added the `_NSLayoutConstraintNumberExceedsLimit()` breakpoint which stops me on this line:

```
NSArray *constraintAircraftV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[xLabelsCV(==lblCvHeight)]-spacing-[timePeriodCV(==timePeriodCvHeight)]-spacing-[aircraftCV(==aircraftCvHeight)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
```

How am I supposed to gel where the issue is here though? Code hasn't changed, but it has just stopped working as of iOS9 update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I don't think that _NSLayoutConstraintNumberExceedsLimit() is causing the crash. It is just a warning. But still, it should be fixed ideally.

Focusing on the crash for now.
The problem lies with :

> [NSLayoutConstraint
>   constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]:
>   A constraint cannot be made between a leading/trailing attribute and a
>   right/left attribute. Use leading/trailing for both or neither.'

Maybe somewhere in your constraints you have associated NSLayoutAttributeLeading for an item to NSLayoutAttributeLeft.
Can you put the code where you add the constraints?

Comment: This was the issue. The trouble I had was finding where in my code I had done this. It was hard to track down. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is a new iOS 9 problem.
replace :

```
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.skipButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailling relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self **attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight** multiplier:XXX constant:XXX]];
```

so that the two  attributes are the same:

```
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.skipButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:XXX constant:XXX]];
```

both cases of **attribute:NSLayoutAttributeXXXX** have to be the same.